# C# Selenium Table Pagination Testing

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I read a lot of comments about this theme but the problem is that more of them used jQuery data tables and the page doesn't reload. In my case, I use a bootstrap table, and on click pagination button I call to action and the page reloads. I use Selenium here and pagination is .NET Html.PagedListPager.But when I loop pagination and try to click each button after the second click throws me an exception: "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document".Is there a most better way to get all clickable pagination buttons? Why I get this exception here `var text = button.Text;`?
My code:

```
var paginationButtons = this.Driver
                            .FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@class,'pagination')]/li/a[contains(@href,'/?page')]"));

//Get All File names from table
var fileNames = new List<string>();

foreach (var button in paginationButtons)
{
    var text = button.Text;
    button.Click();

    this.Driver.WaitForDocumentReady();

    fileNames = this.Driver
        .FindElements(By.XPath("//td[contains(@id,\"FileName\")]"))
        .Select(element => element.Text)
        .ToList();

    if (fileNames.Any(f => !f.Contains("NT13-micro")))
    {
        result = false;
        break;
    }

    paginationButtons= this.Driver
                           .FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@class,'pagination')]/li/a[contains(@href,'/?page')]"));
}
```

Here is the pagination:

```
<div class="col-lg" id="filesListPager">

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Files, page => Url.Action("Files",
        new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, restoreQueryString = false }),
        new PagedListRenderOptions()
        {
            DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true,
            PageCountAndCurrentLocationFormat = "Page {0} of {1}",
            LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<< First",
            LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "< Previous",
            LinkToNextPageFormat = "Next >",
            LinkToLastPageFormat = "Last >>",
            Display = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
            DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = false
        })
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of your code? Two more things that we need: The error message and full stack trace; a representative snippet of HTML for the table you are working with.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question, but you posted the Razor template code, but we need to see the **rendered HTML code in the browser**. A Razor template is on the server, not code rendered in the web browser.